# Can Git use exclusive checkout?

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, tfvc, azure-repos

I want to convince my team leader to switch from TFVC to Git, but the main stumbling block is the exclusive checkout (he love this useless feature), is it possible to have this mechanism using Git and Azure DevOps?

I bought a Mac, and I can't use it as long as they use TFVC

Comment: Maybe I am a bit of of an outlier here, but searching for TFVC exclusive checkout does not seem to give any relevant results. If you explained what that means here, this question would be much easier to answer.

Comment: @Kraigolas it's basically checking out a file with a lock to prevent anybody else to check it out at the same time.

Comment: I wonder why you said "cannot use it", as there are ways (workarounds) to connect to TFVC on macOS, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/tf-version-control?view=vsmac-2019

Comment: To be entirely honest, you *could* set up hooks (this might not be the easiest way) to block people from pushing changes to files you want to reserve as locked. With that said, I personally don't see any reason to do this. If you don't want other devs working on a file, tell them not to. Or block changes to said file if they try to submit them. Git is distributed, so to say two people cannot checkout a file at the same time does not make sense. Everyone will have access to all of the files, it's up to the maintainer of your main branch to decide what gets merged in.

Comment: It looks to me that you do not understand the difference between a centralized VCS and a distributed VCS that git is.

Comment: Why is it that you believe exclusive checkout is useless?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: no, there is no exclusive checkout in git due to git's distributed nature.

Long answer: you can achieve the same workflow in git with some other mechanisms. Your solution will depend on which git server software you will be using. Gitlab supports file locking. As far as I know Bitbucket doesn't support direct file locking, but you can set permissions to lock down a branch, and only allow merges via pull requests. That achieves the same effect (and more) as file locking.

Comment: we use Azure DevOps Server, but I can't see an option like this reading the documentation

Comment: I see you have tagged this question with `azure-devops`. Perhaps add to the question to explicitly state that you are using Azure DevOps, and ask about how to implement this there?

Comment: I added `azure-repos` to your question , as that seems to be the version control part of DevOps.